# win7 32bit CreateFile fail (CD-ROM)

Tags: windows, visual-c++

When I CreateFile (CDROM) on Win7 32bit Enterprise, like that:

```
rv = CreateFile(ifDetail->DevicePath, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE  , FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
```

It's Fail, But when I remove GENERIC_READ, then it's a pass. But SCSI CMD would fail...

```
rv = CreateFile(ifDetail->DevicePath, GENERIC_WRITE  , FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
```

I try this on Win7 64bit which Personal and Enterprise, it works!! and SCSI CMD Success.

Win7 32bit Ultimate pass too!! But Personal and Enterprise Fail. WHY? It's windows drive different?

It's made me Crazy between win7 32bit 64bit Personal Enterprise Ultimate .

Comment: Perhaps you should check the value of `GetLastError()` for more information?

Comment: error code 5 access is denied...